# taking a part of a string in java

Tags: java

I'm new to java and I have a question concerning strings

If I have :

```
String example="PostID:123";
```

How can I get the number 123 and store it in another string ? 
thank you

Comment: If you write this same question title in Google, there will be several answers for this.

Answer (score 3):

One quick approach is to use [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method:

```
String source = "PostID:123";
String[] tokens = source.split(":");
String numberString = tokens[1];
```

This is effective if you know exactly format of source or you know that this format never will change.

Another approach is to use **char-array** and **StringBuilder** (if you don't know exactly format of String and don't like regex :)

```
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(); // or StringBuffer
for (char c: source.toCharArray()) {
   if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
      b.append(c);
   }
}
String numString = b.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) the `String` according to `:` and returning the second part:

```
String newString = example.split(":")[1];
```

If your `String` can be something like: `PostID:123456 xy bla bla bla` you can do:

```
String newString = example.split(":")[1].split(" ")[0]; //Will contain 123456
```

`example.split(":")[1]` will contain `123456 xy bla bla bla` and then we split according to a whitespace, and return the first element, which will contain `123456`.

Note that this solution assumes that the struct of the `String` is exactly as you said. You can achieve better solution for more general Strings, like:

```
String example="PostID   :   12312 xy abc asd ";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(":\\s*(.*?)\\s+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(example);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1)); //Will print 12312
}
```

Comment: and if i have "PostID:123 xy", can I write :
System.out.println(example.split(":")[" "]); to get the number ?

Comment: No, this is a different situation. Change your question. We misunderstood you.

Comment: String example="PostID:randomnumber xy abc", how can I get the random number whatever it is ?

Comment: I want to get the number after PostID: , how can I do it ?

Comment: I told you, look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `substring` methods available in the `String` API.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Answer (score 0):

Use split method of String.

**Edit:** According to comments on another answer... The asker also has spaces so I'm updating the regex to split on `:` or a `space`.

```
public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String example="PostID:123 xy zy";
    String[] vals = example.split(":|\\s");
    for (int i = 0; i < vals.length; i++){
      System.out.println(vals[i]);
    }
  }

}
```

Gives

```
PostID
123
xy
zy
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String example="PostID:123";

String numString = example.subString(example.lastIndexOf(":"));
```